# Capture function name with brackets

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to capture the whole function name for example:

```
player($var)
```

I tried this:

```
preg_match_all('/(function )(?P<name>\w+)/', $content, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

This returns:

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => __construct
                [1] => 140
            )

```
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => player
            [1] => 365
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => creates
            [1] => 13356
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => onYouTubeIframeAPIReady
            [1] => 13475
        )
```

Why is this not returning the function variables?

Comment: I think it is because of the dollar sign which is not in `\w` try with `[\w$]+`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture the variables, change the regex to:

```
/(function )(?P<name>\w+\s*\([^)]*\))/
```

or

```
/(function )(?P<name>\w+)\s*\((P<variables>[^)]*)\)/
```

The function name is the named group `name` and the variables in group `variables`